# making an inline C# call in external Javascript file

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

With my javascript getting bigger and bigger, I want to clean up my ASPX File.

The problem is alot of my javascript involves a lot of inline C# calls. ie:

```
'<%=C# method call)%>'
```

But this doesn't seem to work when its tucked away in a .js file.

Is there a workaround so I can seperate my javascript into js files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly you cannot call C# from a .js file.  C# code is executed on the server, not on the client.  Your .js file is not parsed on the server.

Nothing should prevent you from putting actual JavaScript into a .js file, as opposed to, say, JavaScript that is dynamically emitted by server-side C# code.

If you have a lot of C# code that is generating JavaScript, you can still organize your code by using partial views (that's MVC terminology, but I'm sure there's something similar for standard ASP.Net).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [WebMethods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and call them via Ajax.

```
[WebMethod]
public static int SomeMethod()
{
    ...
}
```

Then call it with Ajax.   (I'm using [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) in this example.)

```
$.ajax({
    type:        "POST"  
    url:         "/yourwebpage.aspx/SomeMethod"
    data:        "{}"
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType:    "json",
    success:     function(data) {
                     // do something with the return value
                 }
});
```